# How to 'rollback' my content to a specific date, reparing an update or delete or insert

Tags: mysql, datetime, triggers, point-in-time-recovery

I am maintaining a MySQL database (roughly 100 tables, lot of relations etc) here (version: 5.7). I am wondering if I can add a table etc (audit-table(s) and/or history-table(s) or add columns to the original tables) so that it will be easier for me to maintain that database in the future (for instance if the user 'joe' inserted/updated and deleted things that he should not have messed with, then I could 'rollback' only his dealings with the database).
Is there a good pattern for this? Or is this functionality already built in the Enterprise-version of for-instance MySQL 5.7 and MySQL 8.x?

I have found articles like this one (1) https://kahimyang.com/kauswagan/code-blogs/552/create-history-record-for-every-change-in-mysql-table-audit-trail-mysql-trigger and this one (2) https://blog.programster.org/mysql-history-tables when searching.
Could you propose or point me to a tutorial or a whitepaper from MySQL on how to do this? Or can you recommend a good book on the subject?

Comment: *if the user 'joe' inserted/updated and deleted things that he should not have messed with* Set correct permissions to the accounts. *then I could 'rollback' only his dealings with the database* It seems that none DBMS supports such "rollback".

Comment: Determining which data modifications (not database transactions) to "roll back" based on some kind of an application logic is a task for the application, not the database. Creating logs of changes are a pre-requisite, but implementing the logic for identifying changes to roll back and to actually roll those changes back are up to the application.

Comment: @Akina, Hi Akina - we cannot do that here, Joe is allowed to do those inserts but seems to miss i.e the coordinates 80 % of the time and I am able to filter out Joe using my audit-table and correct his mistakes. The use-case would be " (1) A person (the manager ) audits the database 4 times a years and is able to filter out Joe ( using the audit-table) making a mistake with the coordinates 80% of the time, how do I fix his mistake ? "

Comment: @Shadow, Hi Shadow. I was thinking more according to these lines -> vladmihalcea.com/mysql-audit-logging-triggers .  Where Vlad creates 2 tables , one 'book'-tbl  and on 'book_audit_log'-tbl , what I am wondering now if it is possible to create a script to 'rollback' using the information in the 'book_audit_log'-table .

Comment: Yes, it is possible to create such script, but that will be specific to your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different approaches to solving this *difficult* problem. It's often called *point-in-time restore* rather than rollback, because ROLLBACK means something else in SQL.

**One:** Add `start_date` and `end_date` columns to your tables along with the other identifying items (`user_id` I guess).  Then, instead of simply doing an UPDATE operation, first UPDATE the `end_date` of the existing row to NOW() and INSERT the new value with a `start_date` of NOW() and a NULL end_date.

When looking up items do this to get their current value.

```
 SELECT col, col, col 
   FROM tbl
  WHERE start_date <= NOW()
    AND (end_date > NOW() OR end_date IS NULL)
    AND whateverElseYouNeed
```

When looking up items for a particular date do this:

```
 SELECT col, col, col 
   FROM tbl
  WHERE start_date <= @date
    AND (end_date > @date OR end_date IS NULL)
    AND whateverElseYouNeed
```

Then you can write code to look up old values and treat them as new values. Indexing these tables so lookups are still efficient when they get really large is a pain in the xxs neck.

**Two:** Create a history table to match each table, but also including a `change_date` column. Write [BEFORE triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) for INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE to insert a row in the history table for each change to the main table. Then write code to look back in the history table when you need to restore something.

This may be best if you already have lots of data.  And, it can implement the required history logging you need without code changes to your existing application. You'll still have to create the code to actually perform the point-in-time restore you need. The good news with this approach is you'll only actually search your history table when you need to restore something, so you don't have to optimize searches.

**Three:** MariaDB, since v 10.3.4, has offered [system-versioned tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/system-versioned-tables/) to handle the history within the database server. (I haven't tried that feature myself.)

Prof. Richard T. Snodgrass wrote [Developing Time-Oriented Database Applications in SQL](https://www.worldcat.org/title/developing-time-oriented-database-applications-in-sql/oclc/156931185) and generously posted a [pdf of the book](http://www2.cs.arizona.edu/%7Erts/tdbbook.pdf).

Comment: @O-Jones  - thanks for the Answer!  I need to discuss this with my fellows, the Snodgrass idea might be too excessivethis issue but I am not sure - need to gain more knowledge in the field. The MariaDB take, that might be the right take. best i

Comment: @O-Jones, I was thinking more according to these lines -> https://vladmihalcea.com/mysql-audit-logging-triggers/ . This technique documents at least every changes. I guess the hard part would be if I would like to 'rollback' or 'point in time restore' an action using this approach.